# Linked Stack Copy Constructor

Tags: c++

```
template<typename T>
LinkedStack<T>::LinkedStack(const LinkedStack<T> &other) {
Node<T> *temp = other.stktop;
if (other.stktop != nullptr) {

    Node<T> *newnode = new Node<T>;
    newnode = temp;

    while (temp->next != nullptr) {
        temp = temp->next;
        newnode->next = temp;
    }
}
}
```

This is my copy constructor.

```
template <typename U>
struct Node {
    U data;
    Node<U> *next;
};

Node<T> *stktop;
```

and this is my struct node located in private section of my LinkedStack Class.
I tried following the logic for writing the copy constructors and I came up with this code.However it doesn't work.Any idea what is wrong?

Comment: You're only copying the pointers from `other`. You need to copy all the nodes.

Comment: Do you mean I am only copying the pointers and not copying the data in the nodes?

Comment: First, do you know what the concept of copy construction is?  It is to create another totally separate LinkedList object that has the same structure and data as the original.  Once this copy is created, it can live on its own and doesn't need to refer to any data or nodes in the original object.  Does your code do that, i.e. create such a copy?  It certainly doesn't, so given the high-level of what copy construction means, rewrite your code (or better yet, plan out before writing any code) to accomplish copy construction.

Comment: @JohnMert Yes, `newnode->next = temp;`  is assigning a pointer value to another pointer, it doesn't copy the node it points to. (And `newnode = temp;` is leaking the only node you're creating, by overwriting the value of `newnode`.) You need one `new` for each node in the list you're copying.

Answer (score 0):

Something like that:

```
template<typename T>
LinkedStack<T>::LinkedStack(const LinkedStack<T> &other)
{
    // Create first node
    if (!other.stktop) // Use pointer to bool cast
    {
        stktop = new Node<T>;
        // Copy data. This is the simplest copy if U support it.
        stktop->data = other.stktop->data;
    }
    else
    {
        stktop = nullptr; // Very important otherwise its value is undefined
        return;
    }

    auto pothernode = other.stktop;
    auto pthisnode = stktop;

    // Iterate overall the elements
    while (pothernode->next)
    {
        pthisnode->next = new Node<T>;
        pthisnode->next->data = pothernode->next->data;

        pothernode = pothernode->next;
        pthisnode = pthisnode->next;
    }
}
```

Note that all the nodes are allocated on the heap so do not forget to delete them. I suggest to use `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr` instead of pure pointer.

Some possible optimization:

```
template<typename T>
LinkedStack<T>::LinkedStack(const LinkedStack<T> &other)
{
    const auto& pothernode = other.stktop;
    auto& pthisnode = stktop;
    pthisnode = nullptr;

    // Iterate overall the elements
    while (pothernode)
    {
        pthisnode = new Node<T>;
        pthisnode->data = pothernode->data;

        pothernode = pothernode->next;
        pthisnode = pthisnode->next;
    }
}
```